# Can not insert FeedItem through apexrest

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, feeditem

When trying to create a FeedItem through the ApexRest I'm always getting the following error:

> [{"errorCode":"APEX_ERROR","message":"System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Body]: [Body]\n\nClass.WS_SALES_V1_Document.post: line 61, column 1"}]

But according to the [Salesforce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm), the Body field is *Optional when Type is ContentPost*.
Apex code of FeedItem creation(the `insert fi;` is line 61 by the way):

```
FeedItem fi = new FeedItem();
fi.ParentId = o.Id;
fi.Type = 'ContentPost';
fi.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
insert fi;
```

Is it a bug? Is documentation not up-to-date?

**EDIT**

I'm using API version 36.0

Comment: As per the same doc `If you set Type to ContentPost, also specify ContentData and ContentFileName.` so give these two and then try.

Comment: @TusharSharma thanks for the comment, but according to that same doc, both `ContentData` and `ContentFileName` are *Available in API version 35.0 and earlier only.*

Comment: @Novarg .. I think Tushar is right about it. Here is the latest documentation URL, the url you pointed is of 2016. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm here it say those two Tushar mentioned are required fields

Answer (score -1):

The error says you have to include the Body field.  fi.Body = 'body text';

Comment: For type content, body is not required but attachments are.